# Register button not working in registration_form.html django

Tags: html, django

I've been following the How to Django 1.9 tutorials and I came across a problem. My registration_form.html has been working properly ever since installment but after adding bootstrap to the template, the registration button has no action. This is the registration_form.html without the bootstrap

```
{% extends "rango/base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}
  <h1>Register Here</h1>
  <form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the registration_template with the bootstrap

```
{% extends 'rango/base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
<link href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-5">Register</h1>
</div>
<form role="form" method='post' action='.'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="required"><label class="required" for="id_username">Username:</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" />
        <span class="helptext">
        Required. 30 charachters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.
        </span>
        </p>
    <p class="required"><label class="required" for="id_email">Email:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_email" name="email" type="email"/>
    </p>
    <p class="required"><label class="required" for="id_password1">Password:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password"/>
    </p>
    <p class="required"><label class="required" for="id_password2">Password Confirmation:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_password2"  name="password2" type="password" />
    </p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value='Submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
<p>
    Already a member?
    <a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">Log In Here!</a>
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What happens when you click on Submit button?

Comment: It just refreshes the page. It does nothing

Comment: Please show your view and your form. You haven't included the form errors, so you can't see what the problem is. See the docs on [rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually). It's easy to make mistakes when rendering fields manually. You might find [crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) useful if you want to render forms using bootstrap.

Comment: I'm using django-registration-redux so it basically has its own in-built views and forms

Comment: Can you please add your **urls.py** and **views.py** files.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **url** in your template form under `action` attribute as showed below:

```
<form role="form" method='post' action='{% url 'example' %}'>
```

This may fix your issues!!!.Make sure that your form has no errors.Try to add your `views.py`,`urls.py` and `models.py`, so we can figure it out easily.

Answer (score 0):

Must be an input type not a button type use `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value='Submit'>Submit</button>` instead

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value='Submit'>Submit</button>
```